# Limit wordpress user login maximum to two device at same time

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using paidmembershipspro for wordpress. I want to limit user to login from 2 device at a time for particular membership plan.

I used to manage to restrict user to one login at same time but not two.

Comment: You can just add IP adress vertification into your login page code.

Comment: what if multiple devices attached to same IP like router ?? can it be possible using session_id() ??

Comment: Well if multiple devices share one router, those device's public IP adress will be the same. Also, if you copy the session cookie from one device and insert it into another device, it will work (in case you dont logout using `session_destroy()` or so).

Comment: can you please check http://benmay.org/wordpress/single-user-wordpress/ this works for one device at time same functionality i want for two device

Comment: I doubt that you can edit that code to work for multiple machines automatically. Do you need to relog? Using same cookie would be the solution.

Comment: This is a Wordpress administration question, not a "programming question" in the sense that StackOverflow focuses on.  Perhaps this question would be more fitting for [WordPress StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) *(if they consider paidmembershipspro admin on-topic, I wouldn't know.)*